# Implement an interface with a default property, in cli/c++

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I'm trying to declare several indexed properties as part of an interface in C#. 
The aim being able to write something like:
int v=obj.Field1[4]+obj.Field2[4];

The implementation is done in C++/CLI.

I've found info about the use of a 'proxy' to approach the behaviour in
[Named indexed property in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081402/named-indexed-property-in-c/23081403#23081403)

C#:

```
public interface IMyProp1
{
  int this[int idx] { get; }
}
public interface IMyProp2
{
  int this[int idx] { get; }
}


public interface IMyThing: IMyProp1, IMyProp2
{
 IMyProp1 Field1;
 IMyProp2 Field2;
}
```

In C++/CLI, I've found some info here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f1ec0b1.aspx
But it's not specific about interface
I've written the following (trial and error with the help of the VS2015 compiler)

```
public ref class MyThing: IMyThing
{
  virtual property int default[int]
  {
    int get(int idx) { return fld1[idx]; }
  }
  virtual property IMyProp1 Field1 { IMyProp1 get() { return this; } }
  virtual property IMyProp2 Field2 { IMyProp2 get() { return this; } }
private:
  array<int>^ fld1;
  array<int>^ fld2;

}
```

But I don't see how I can implement 2 different behaviours, as

`virtual property int default[int]`

is unique. Even if there are 2 'different' interfaces (I concede it's the same signature), I can't figure out a way to specify 2 different implementations:

```
virtual property int IMyProp1::default[int] { int get(int idx) { return fld1[idx]; }
virtual property int IMyProp2::default[int] { int get(int idx) { return fld2[idx]; }
```

I've found this information about explicit interface implementation in C++

```
interface class MyInterface1 { void f(); };
interface class MyInterface2 { void f(); };
ref class MyClass : MyInterface1, MyInterface2
{
  public:
  virtual void f1() = MyInterface1::f
  {
    Console::WriteLine("MyClass::f1 == MyInterface1::f");
  }

  virtual void f2() = MyInterface2::f
  {
    Console::WriteLine("MyClass::f2 == MyInterface2::f");
  }
};
```

But can't figure out a way to mix that with the indexed property signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For explicit implementation of properties, you specify the explicit override on each accessor method.

Try something like:

```
virtual property int Indexer1[int]
{
    int get(int idx) = IMyProp1::default[int]::get { return fld1[idx]; }
}
```

Comment: That was it! I hadn't found this info from MSDN, they only document that the syntax changed from managed c++, but they didn't mention that you had to override each accessor. Thanks Ben!