# Tracking down the cause of a NaN float

Tags: c#

I've got  float array

```
public float[] Outputs;
```

Somewhere in my code, something is updating the array values and causing a NaN. This is a **very** infrequent error and I can't work out for the life of me what's causing it.

How can I make a change with minimal code alteration to track it down? It'd be good to make that array private and rename it, then create a property called Outputs for getting and setting that does a NaN check every time it's set. Then I can easily raise an exception when the NaN is set and retrieve a call stack, rather than discovering it further down the line when another piece of code tries to use it. Something like this - that actually compiles.

I get the error:

```
"Bad array declarator: To declare a managed array the rank specifier precedes 
 the variable's identifier. To declare a fixed size buffer field, use the fixed 
 keyword before the field type."
```

Here is my code:

```
    public float[] _outputs;

    public float Outputs[int index]   
    {
        get
        {
            return _outputs[index];
        }
        set
        {
            if (float.IsNaN(value))
                throw new Exception("Blar blar");
            _outputs[index] = value;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Thanks for an answers people, anyone else looking for answers may want to read this:
[Why C# doesn't implement indexed properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806894/why-c-sharp-doesnt-implement-indexed-properties)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why doesn't this work?

Comment: I've updated it to make the question more clear. I can't get the code to compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use named indexers in C#, as a workaround you could do something like:

```
public class Indexer<T>
{
    private T[] _values;

    public Indexer(int capacity)
    {
        _values = new T[capacity];
    }

    protected virtual void OnValueChanging(T value)
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return _values[index]; }
        set
        {   
            OnValueChanging(value);
            _values[index] = value;
        }
    }
}

public class FloatIndexer : Indexer<float>
{
    public FloatIndexer(int capacity)
        : base(capacity)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnValueChanging(float value)
    {
        if (float.IsNaN(value))
            throw new Exception("Blar blar");
    }
}

public class Container
{
    public Container()
    {
        Outputs = new FloatIndexer(3);
    }

    public FloatIndexer Outputs { get; private set; }
}
...
var container = new Container();
container.Outputs[0] = 2.5f;
container.Outputs[1] = 0.4f;
container.Outputs[2] = float.NaN; // BOOM!
...
```

I updated this to be more generic so you could re-use it for various other types, not just `float`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's not possible to declare a indexer with a specific name. You must wrap a object around it and use:

```
public float this[int index] { ...}
```

In your case you could use a wrapper class for this case:

```
public class ArrayWrapper
{
    public float this[int index] { ...}
    public ArrayWrapper(float[] values) { .... }
}
```

To use it you need  to use the `ArrayWrapper`-class as property type.

As alternative you could use a extension method ( Not so fine because you need to change code ):

```
public static void SetFloat(this float[] @this, int index, float value) { ... }
```

And use it this way:

```
targetObject.Outputs.SetFloat(0, Single.NaN);
```

Comment: The extension method suggestion would also need the `index` to be passed in as an argument.

Comment: @James Right i made this really quick and forget it.