# Is it possible to make multi-parameter properties?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
class blabla
{
   string[] a;
   string ciao(int row, string text)
   {
       set { a[row] = text;}
       get { return a[row;}
   }
}
```

(yeah i know i can just make my own method eventually)

Comment: Yes, they call them "methods"

Comment: [Indexers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)

Comment: Depending on the context, you may want [Indexed properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Related: [Why C# doesn't implement indexed properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2806894/11683)

Answer (score 6):

This best you can do is using the index property, `this`:

```
class Foo
{
 string[] row;

 string this[int row]
 {
    set {a[row] = value;}
    get {return a[row];}
 }
}
```

Then, you access it using the `[]` operator:

```
Foo f;
f[1] = "hello";
```

It's not possible to have a named property that behaves this way.

As an interesting aside, there's no reason, from a .NET, that properties can't be parameterized. If you look at the [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class you can see that a property is just a get method and a set method, both of which can take parameters. In fact this is how the index property works (along with an attribute). It's just that C# doesn't expose this functionality through the language.

Comment: Re aside: it's one of the features that [VB has](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc3dtbky.aspx) and C# doesn't.

Comment: I just tried to create a class in VB that has parameterized property `Bar` and reference it from a C# project. The class is shown by C#'s IntelliSense as having two separate methods, `get_Bar` and `set_Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an indexer property

```
public string this[int index]
```

Overloads the [] operator on your class, allowing you to take a parameter between the [] and after the =

You could change the type of the index parameter, but this will probably be confusing to the caller.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464(v=vs.71).aspx

```
class blabla
{
   private string[] a;
   string this[int row]
   {
       set { a[row] = value;}
       get { return a[row;}
   }
}
```

The syntax works so that the type of `value` is specified by the return type of the overloaded operator.