# VB.Net WriteOnly Property to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I wrote this class as part of a custom control in VB.Net. It lets me toggle the state of 3 linked labels, and set the text of each one using the Text property. That is all the user is allowed to do with it. I can convert the Enabled property and constructor without issue, however I am unsure as the best method to convert the Text property. A function would take  2 arguments, and an indexer would act on LabelExtender3, not on Text as it currently does in VB.Net. So what is the correct way to convert something like this?

```
Public Class LabelExtender3
    Private lblTemp(2) As Label

    Public WriteOnly Property Enabled As Boolean
        Set(value As Boolean)
            If value Then
                lblTemp(0).ForeColor = Color.MediumBlue
                lblTemp(1).ForeColor = Color.MediumBlue
                lblTemp(2).ForeColor = Color.MediumBlue
            Else
                lblTemp(0).ForeColor = Color.SteelBlue
                lblTemp(1).ForeColor = Color.SteelBlue
                lblTemp(2).ForeColor = Color.SteelBlue
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public WriteOnly Property Text(ByVal index As Integer) As String
        Set(value As String)
            lblTemp(index).Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Friend Sub New(ByRef value1 As Label, ByRef value2 As Label, ByRef value3 As Label)
        lblTemp(0) = value1
        lblTemp(1) = value2
        lblTemp(2) = value3
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make multi-parameter properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190900/is-it-possible-to-make-multi-parameter-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've come across a feature that VB.NET has that C# does not: indexable properties.

More specifically, C# lacks the ability to declare them, but it is able to consume them (which was added in C# 4.0) and that might be limited to COM Interop use.

Your best bet it to just make a method in this case:

```
public void SetText(int index, string value)
{
    lblTemp[index].Text = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# does not allow properties with parameters so there is no direct conversion of this but you can just create a method instead.

Try Using [Instant C#](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Instant_CSharp.html) I find it the best tool for conversions (I am in no way affiliated to this company):

```
//INSTANT C# NOTE: C# does not support parameterized properties - the following property has been rewritten as a 'set' method:
//ORIGINAL LINE: Public WriteOnly Property Text(ByVal index As Integer) As String
    public void set_Text(int index, string value)
    {
        lblTemp[index].Text = value;
    }
```

Comment: You are not using proper naming conventions.

Comment: @fsacer People can use whatever naming conventions they want. Secondly, the code is from a conversation tool. The conversion tool is likely using the name `set_Text` because that is what the setter method is named in CIL when compiled by VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

In C# `WriteOnly` property equates to a C# property with only a `set` part. But you cannot pass the parameter to C# property unless it is an indexer so it becomes a method. So you would convert the code into:

```
public class LabelExtender3
{

    private Label[] lblTemp = new Label[3];
    public bool Enabled
    {
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                lblTemp[0].ForeColor = Color.MediumBlue;
                lblTemp[1].ForeColor = Color.MediumBlue;
                lblTemp[2].ForeColor = Color.MediumBlue;
            }
            else
            {
                lblTemp[0].ForeColor = Color.SteelBlue;
                lblTemp[1].ForeColor = Color.SteelBlue;
                lblTemp[2].ForeColor = Color.SteelBlue;
            }
        }
    }

    public string SetText(int index, string value)
    {
        lblTemp[index].Text = value;
    }

    internal LabelExtender3(ref Label value1, ref Label value2, ref Label value3)
    {
        lblTemp[0] = value1;
        lblTemp[1] = value2;
        lblTemp[2] = value3;
    }
}
```