# How do I find the generated "indexer" code in C#?

Tags: c#, indexer

I have read the [Indexer docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers) and I know that indexer will be translate to generate a property named "Item". I want to inspect the generated code but I can't find the process function of compiler how to generate it. [Source Code search of C#](https://source.dot.net/)

Comment: Do you want to see the implementation? Or do you just want to know how to reference the `.Item` via reflection. It would help if you explained more on _Why_ you want to do this or how you will use the information.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I want to see the implementation code. Thanks

Comment: I know that "Reflection" can iterate all property in an object. I am curious about how the compiler translate the "indexer" code to "Item" property. @ChrisSchaller

Comment: If you want to see how the compiler generates the indexer property, you might want to start with the CSharp compiler source rather than the .NET source. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, property getters accept no parameters, and setters accept exactly one parameter only, so it is rather impossible for the compiler to generate a *C#* property (in the C# sense) for the indexer. If you expected to find C# code declaring a property called `Item`, you won't find that.

What the compiler does generate, is IL, and this is what the documentation meant - "property" in the IL sense. IL has indexed properties, and that's what indexers translate to. For example, an indexer like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string this[int index]
    {
        get => "";
        set {}
    }
}
```

translates to (play with this on [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQGID2ZOA3jgXUYcugAwHAAWYAzgNpgB2wAgJgBTAB4BdWvRrZ6CggHNRQgLwA+AgCJtAbhmKCXVQSoBfQwUvZzQA==)!):

```
.method public hidebysig specialname 
    instance string get_Item (
        int32 index
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 6 (0x6)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldstr ""
    IL_0005: ret
} // end of method Foo::get_Item

.method public hidebysig specialname 
    instance void set_Item (
        int32 index,
        string 'value'
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2057
    // Code size 2 (0x2)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ret
} // end of method Foo::set_Item

// Properties
.property instance string Item(
    int32 index
)
{
    .get instance string Foo::get_Item(int32)
    .set instance void Foo::set_Item(int32, string)
}
```

Notice that the `Item` property "takes a parameter". There is also a [`DefaultMemberAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.defaultmemberattribute?view=net-5.0) added (not shown above).

Compare that last part with what normal C# properties translate to:

```
.property instance string Item()
{
    .get instance string Foo::get_Item()
    .set instance void Foo::set_Item(string)
}
```

Note that if you translate the IL code back to C#, you'll get the indexer back. [Indexed properties don't exist in C#.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806894/why-c-sharp-doesnt-implement-indexed-properties)